# Having an issue getting an ActionResult that uses parameters to return specific queryable items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I am trying to get this Action Result to use the parameters given (Year, Qtr, Div) and only return those results. I use something similar to this in other ActionResults, but they do not return results in Json. I am not quite sure what I need to do in order to get this result to return only the results that match the parameters given. What it is doing is returning all records instead of filtering them by the parameters.

```
    public ActionResult GLAcctsISDs_Read([DataSourceRequest]  DataSourceRequest request, int? Year, int? Qtr, string Div)
    {
        var glacctsisds = db.GLAcctsISDs.AsQueryable();
        if (Year.HasValue)
            glacctsisds = glacctsisds.Where(x => x.Year == Year);
        if (Qtr.HasValue)
            glacctsisds = glacctsisds.Where(x => x.Qtr == Qtr);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Div))
            glacctsisds = glacctsisds.Where(x => x.Div == Div);

        DataSourceResult result = glacctsisds.ToDataSourceResult(request, gLAcctsISD => new {

            ID = gLAcctsISD.ID,
            Div = gLAcctsISD.Div,
            Year = gLAcctsISD.Year,
            Qtr = gLAcctsISD.Qtr,
            GLAcct = gLAcctsISD.GLAcct,
            GLDescr = gLAcctsISD.GLDescr,
            TBDebit = gLAcctsISD.TBDebit,
            TBCredit = gLAcctsISD.TBCredit,
            IncExpAdjDebit = gLAcctsISD.IncExpAdjDebit,
            IncExpAdjCredit = gLAcctsISD.IncExpAdjCredit,
            AdlTrialDebit = gLAcctsISD.AdlTrialDebit,
            AdjTrialCredit = gLAcctsISD.AdjTrialCredit,
            RemainExpDebit = gLAcctsISD.RemainExpDebit,
            PendingIncomeCredit = gLAcctsISD.PendingIncomeCredit,
            ProjRemainExpDebit = gLAcctsISD.ProjRemainExpDebit,
            NetIncomeCredit = gLAcctsISD.NetIncomeCredit,
            DivGLNotes = gLAcctsISD.DivGLNotes
        });


        return Json(result);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: put a breakpoint and see whether you are getting a NON NULLABLE value for the `Year`,`Qtr` and `Div` parameters.

Comment: Yes, I am getting nulls for some reason. Is my syntax not right at the top where I list the parameters. The address link shows that they are getting passed.....http://localhost:12153/KendoGLAcctISD/KenodGLAcctISDList?Year=2015&Qtr=3&Div=ISD

Comment: I figured it out. Telerik UI for MVC is a total different animal than normal MVC code.

Answer (score 0):

try serializing "result" object to json.

```
string jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);

return Json(jsonString);
```

Comment: Yah that will not because you have to check first why are you getting nulls.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to know how to do this here you go:
Parameters are passed in to the controller as year, qtr, and div:

```
 public ActionResult KenodGLAcctISDList( int? year, int? qtr, string div)
    {
        ViewBag.YYear = year;
        ViewBag.QQtr = qtr;
        ViewBag.DDiv = div;
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GLAcctsISDs_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {

        var glacctsisds = db.GLAcctsISDs.AsQueryable();
        DataSourceResult result = glacctsisds.ToDataSourceResult(request, gLAcctsISD => new {

            ID = gLAcctsISD.ID,
            Div = gLAcctsISD.Div,
            Year = gLAcctsISD.Year,
            Qtr = gLAcctsISD.Qtr,
            GLAcct = gLAcctsISD.GLAcct,
            GLDescr = gLAcctsISD.GLDescr,
            TBDebit = gLAcctsISD.TBDebit,
            TBCredit = gLAcctsISD.TBCredit,
            IncExpAdjDebit = gLAcctsISD.IncExpAdjDebit,
            IncExpAdjCredit = gLAcctsISD.IncExpAdjCredit,
            AdlTrialDebit = gLAcctsISD.AdlTrialDebit,
            AdjTrialCredit = gLAcctsISD.AdjTrialCredit,
            RemainExpDebit = gLAcctsISD.RemainExpDebit,
            PendingIncomeCredit = gLAcctsISD.PendingIncomeCredit,
            ProjRemainExpDebit = gLAcctsISD.ProjRemainExpDebit,
            NetIncomeCredit = gLAcctsISD.NetIncomeCredit,
            DivGLNotes = gLAcctsISD.DivGLNotes
        });


        return Json(result);
    }
```

Then passed to the view as Viewbags and sorted by the KendoUI Grid code

```
.Read(read => read.Action("GLAcctsISDs_Read", "KendoGLAcctISD"))
      .Filter(filter =>
              {
                  filter.Add(f => f.Year).IsEqualTo(ViewBag.YYear);
                  filter.Add(f => f.Qtr).IsEqualTo(ViewBag.QQtr);

              })
      .Update(update => update.Action("GLAcctsISDs_Update", "KendoGLAcctISD"))
```